# Literal Control <li> inline edit

Tags: c#, asp.net

i would like to edit text and save it, but inline, this is, the text is uploaded to a literal control in the server, but now i would like to edit the text inline.

User Control - ASP.NET

...

```
+ "<td>" + status + "</td>"
```

...

```
load.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(_str));
```

_str is a string with the literal control;

status is the string wich as the data from the database.

[image: status]

my idea is to click in the numbers and edit. how can i do it?

Comment: The easiest solution would be to make the status a text box, rather than plain text.  If it must be plain text, then you will need javascript to replace the text with a textbox upon clicking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [inline edit control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165554/inline-edit-control)

Comment: it's not the same problem.

Comment: this is working with literal controls, wich is different from text boxes wich in this case are written in asp.

Comment: By textbox, I meant the HTML <input type="text"> tag, not the .NET control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could render the status as a disabled borderless textbox (input="text"). Meaning that it would seem as plain text to the user. When the user clicks on it, you would change the textbox style to make it visible (with borders) and editable (focusable, enabled). The saving process of that information could be made when the user leaves the textbox (onblur event), making an AJAX request to the server or just when the user clicks on a save button (assuming it could exist).